# insert UITextField (from a UIAlertController) into an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, nsmutablearray

Hello I am tying to insert user input attained from an alert txtfield into a mutable array.

So, I have a tableView with a button to add a additional row. When the button is pressed the user can enter a message.

I would like to have that message be inserted into my array.

I was going to use the method clickedButtonAtIndex but Xcode states that that method is now deprecated.

Is there any other way to go about doing this??

here is the code for my array:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

self.exampleMessages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Example Message..", @"Example Message..",@"Example Message..",@"Example Message..",@"Example Message..", @"Example Message..",@"Example Message..",@"Example Message..", nil];}
```

here is my function that is executed once the add row button is pressed:

```
- (void)insertNewObject
//function that is executed after a new object is inserted
{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@""
                                message:nil
                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    //create a UIAlert named alert

    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *messageTextField) {
         messageTextField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"message content", @"Message");
    }];
    //add a UITextField to the UIAlert

    UIAlertAction *messageAction = [UIAlertAction
                                    actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Add", @"Message action")
                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                        UITextField *userMessage = alert.textFields.firstObject;
                                        NSLog(@"%@", userMessage);
                                        //capture the value of the UITextField
                                    }];
    //add a button called "add"

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action")
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {}];
    //add a button called "cancel"

    [alert addAction:messageAction];
    //add the add button to the alert
    [alert addAction:cancelAction];
    //add the cancel button to the alert
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    //present the alert to the UI
}
```

In the code right here I am capturing the value and storing it in a variable but now how do I put it in my array?

```
 UITextField *userMessage = alert.textFields.firstObject;
                                    NSLog(@"%@", userMessage);
                                    //capture the value of the UITextField
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace comment

```
//capture the value of the UITextField
```

with the following line:

```
[self.exampleMessages addObject:userMessage.text ?: @""];
```

Looks like after that you will need to update table view, via `[self.tableView reloadData]` or similar call.

Comment: hhmmm I see how that would work but when I added it to my code nothing happened. The message was not added to my array. Do I need to update my array maybe? like after a message is added?

Comment: I've edited my answer just moment ago. If that doesn't help, I suggest to check `self.exampleMessages` property value right after adding text to array. F.e. add `NSLog(@"%@", self.exampleMessages)` and check logs.

Comment: I saw your comment before you updated your comment, reloading the table view worked!